# How do I update the Cordova version used by VS2017 Apache cordova Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Despite having globally installed Cordova version 7.0.1, when trying to build on Visual Studio 2017 Cordova Tools, it logs:

**Cordova 6.3.1**

There are no available updates for this VS extension.

How can I make it use Cordova 7.0.1?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to [Change the CLI version of your Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova project](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/change-cli-version/).

Comment: @Elvis Xia: Have you tried this for Cordova 7.0.1? If I change the config to use 'Global Cordova 7.0.1' it compiles fine with this version. But on a restart, VS tells me, that a update of my project is necessary and the version is changed back to 6.3.1.
I'm using VS Version 15.3.0 Preview 7

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution yet?

Comment: This problem still exists.. Can anyone from the Cordova Team address it ASAP please?

Comment: did anyone the find any solution for above problem ?

Comment: With Visual Studio 2015 you can check the "use globally installed Cordova version" and use Cordova 7.1.0 without problems. However, VS persists in using an old android-cordova version (6.3.0) and this I cannot update.

Comment: have you updated the toolsetVersion in config.xml?